# Is it possible to implement a memory pool that works with arrays instead of single objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

I know it's easy to make a memory pool for single objects, however I need to make a memory pool for arrays. The memory pool I have currently has a vector of addresses to contiguous memory blocks and a stack that points to each object from these blocks, so when you allocate from the pool you just pop the stack and when you free, you just push an object's address back to it. However I also need an array equivalent. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class ArrayPool
{
public:
ArrayPool();
~ArrayPool();

T* AllocateArray(int x); //Returns a pointer to a T array that contains 'x' elements.
void FreeArray(T* arr, int x); //Returns the array to the free address list/stack/whatever/
};
```

Has such a thing been implemented? I imagine a big problem from having such a pool - if make sure arrays returned by ALlocateArray are contiguous in memory, I'm basically doing the same as if not having a memorypool. Just allocating arrays on the spot. With the normal object pool every time I just allocate 1 object. With the arrays I may allocate a different sized array every time, so once an array is freed, it won't be compatible with a new one of different size, unless I stich arrays together with some linkedlist-like structure, but then they won't be contiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your allocator takes advantage of the fact that all allocations are the same size. This simplifies and speeds up allocation and freeing, and means memory fragmentation is impossible.

If you have to allocate arrays of any size, then what you want is a general-purpose allocator, not a pool allocator. What to do next depends why you're using a pool allocator in the first place. I can think of two other features of a pool allocator that might be relevant, and there may be others:

- all memory comes from a particular region specified when you create the pool
- all memory can be freed at once without freeing each individual allocation, by resetting the pool.

If you don't need any special features of controlling allocation yourself then just use `vector` or global `operator new` or `malloc` to allocate your memory. If you do need special features then you'll probably want to take an allocator off the shelf rather than implementing your own. If you really want to get into the details of how a good memory allocator works then look at http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html and perhaps adapt it to your use.

But if you really need to hand-roll an allocator for limited purposes, then the basic idea is that instead of a list of free nodes from which you can always take the first, you need some data structure (your choice what) containing free blocks of different sizes, that allows you to quickly find a block that's big enough to satisfy the current request. In the case where it's much bigger you might choose to split the block, return part of it, and keep the rest as a new smaller free block. In the case where two free blocks are adjacent you might choose to merge them into a single larger free block.

One common strategy is to keep pool-like lists of blocks of certain sizes (for example 16, 32, 64...). If the request is small enough, satisfy it using one of these. If not, do something more complex. But as I say, if you want to see a lot of tricks working together then look at dlmalloc.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is having fixed sizes and only work on those. For example 400st 32 byte arrays, 200 128b, 100 1024b, 50 8096b or something like that. When something ask for an array of size N you match to the closest size with a free array.

How many you need to each size is probably up for a lot of tweaking.

That would allow you to re-use arrays much more freely than allowing custom sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to win from this? Why isn't it enough just to treat each array as an object? Unless you are *direly* strapped for memory or the time to construct the array elements is really excessive and not to be wasted, this sounds like a classic case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). And if the above are your problems, I'd explore other data structures (not arrays) first before plunging into this.
Your time (getting this working and its quirks ironed out will be a week or so, methinks) is *way* more valuable than a few pennies of computer time or memory saved.